# Stack structure after function call with parameters

Tags: c, memory-management

I was just looking into the memory allocation of a program in `C`. I know that all the global and static variables are stored in a heap. Also, the stack stores all the function calls. I do have one doubt here though. Say I am calling the following function:

```
int ret;
int num = 10;
int arr[3] = {1,2,3};
int *ptr = &arr[0];
ret = giveNumber(num, ptr);
```

Here, I read that the parameters of the function call `giveNumer()` would also be stored in the same stack. But in what order will they be stored? If I popped the top of stack, which parameter will be popped first, `num` or `ptr`?

Comment: Depends on your architecture and has nothing to do with your debugger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I know that all the global and static variables are stored in a heap**.
No, thats not true.
As per the standard they are stored in implementation defined memory regions, typically the Data segment and the BSS.

**If I popped the top of stack, which parameter will be popped first, `num` or `ptr`**
The order of evaluation of arguments to a function is **Unspecified**.
So it depends on your compiler implementation. An compiler might evaluate the arguments from:

- Left to Right or
- Right to Left or
- Any other random order

So the behavior & order you see would depend on this.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what @Als has already mentioned, *most of the compilers on x86* follow `_cdecl` calling convention where arguments are evaluated from right to left. Learn more here

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Calling_Conventions#Standard_C_Calling_Conventions